# Complex numbers proof verification

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers

While playing around, I discovered something and am not sure if it is correct.

Assuming that

> $e^{it} = \cos(t) + i\sin(t)$

Then $e^i=\cos 1+i\sin 1$

But then

> $e^{it} = {(e^i)}^t=\big( \cos 1+i\sin 1 \big)^t$

I have a calculator that unfortunately can only compute to $z^3$ but it was correct for the $2$ values I checked. Is it correct? Does it hold for fractional, negative or complex $t$? I apologize for the title but I do not know how to describe this. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: The "identity" $z^{tx}=(z^x)^t$ is not correct if $z\notin \mathbb R$, because in that case the exponential function with base $z$ is a multifunction. See, for example, [this post of Piero d'Ancona](https://mathoverflow.net/a/94833/13042).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equality$$e^{it}=(\cos1+i\sin 1)^t$$is neither correct nor wrong unless you tell us how do you define $(\cos1+i\sin 1)^t$. Of course, if $t$ is a natural number then this is just $\cos1+i\sin 1$ times itself $t$ times. But how do you define, say, $(\cos1+i\sin 1)^\pi$? Without an answer to this question, your question cannot be answered for a general $t$.

Comment: That was my question. I am unsure of what to do in those cases. The Wikipedia page did help clear some doubts but more remain. anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) for $t$ integer the equality

$$e^{it} = {(e^i)}^t=\big( \cos 1+i\sin 1 \big)^t= \cos (1\cdot t)+i\sin (1\cdot t) $$

holds but for general $t$ it doesn't hold, for that refer to [Generalized De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Failure_for_non-integer_powers,_and_generalization).

Comment: How do we get from $(\cos 1 +i\sin 1)^t=\cos t+i\sin t?$ I get that they are equivalent but is there a way to prove it without going back to $e^{it}?$

Comment: Refer to the given link, we have that $$(\cos x +i\sin x)^n=\cos (nx)+i\sin (nx)$$ and that holds also for non integer exponent.

Comment: Thank you for your help!